# Flutter secure storage write not working properly on web - NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'generateKey' on null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-secure-storage

Having issue with storing data using flutter secure storage.
Issue is seen only when I host the release web build with some server (like apache2).
While runing the app using flutter run -d chrome, it is working fine.
Also the release version for iOS and android versions are working fine.

The issue I am getting is:
`NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'generateKey' on null`

Code:

```
if (isMasterPasswordCorrect == true) {
                                        print(
                                            'master password is correct-----');
                                        print(masterPasswordController.text);
                                        final secureStorage =
                                            new FlutterSecureStorage();
                                        try {
                                          print(
                                              'writing master password data into secure storage');
                                          await secureStorage.write(
                                              key: 'masterPassword',
                                              value: masterPasswordController
                                                  .text);
                                          print(
                                              'reading master password from secure storage');
                                          _isMasterPasswordPresent =
                                              await secureStorage.read(
                                                  key: 'masterPassword');

                                          print(
                                              '${_isMasterPasswordPresent}');
                                        } catch (e) {
                                          print(e);
                                        }
}
```

Output

```
main.dart.js:21714 master password is correct-----
main.dart.js:21714 14000
main.dart.js:21714 writing master password data into secure storage
main.dart.js:21714 NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'generateKey' on null
```

Comment: Raised an issue for the same
https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues/404

Comment: Did you find Solution to this issue?

Comment: @Sulfy yes. I had to use a https server instead of http. Basically, secure_storage needs https to work unless it's a dev env.